# How to set in JavaScript qlikviews checkbox

Tags: javascript, definition, qlikview

I wanna know how do i write the code in javascript so that appers in a properties page in the Qlikview Server and the text tag or label is defined in the .
Actually i have to set the checkbox marked (checked) in javascript.!!

```
<Text   [Label=""] [Type="text,checkbox,select,color"]  [Select=""] [SelectLabel=""] [Width=""]  [Expression=""]  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value of a checkbox or input with  `_this.Layout.SetProperty("Chart.Text.7.Content",1,true);` if input box or checkbox is the seventh for example `_this.Layout.Text7.text`